# Using php to export mysql data into a Macintosh CSV file

Tags: php, macos, file, csv, export

I'm exporting data from MySql to csv file in order to import this on a Sage Contaplus. This is the code:

```
function crearCSV(){
include ("connection.php");
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export_fact.csv');
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
$nl = "\n";
/* here i select data from x tables and echo the results */
```

All it's OK excepting that when i download the CSV file, i have to open and save as CSV (Macintosh), otherwise, Sage's contaplus cannot read the file properly.

How can I generate a CSV (Macintosh) on my code to avoid this step?

Thanks!

Comment: I only need to generate a macintosh csv file, don't need one that work with windows too.

Comment: It is probably an encoding issue: http://superuser.com/questions/385265/whats-the-difference-between-csv-ms-dos-csv-macintosh-csv-comma-delimi

Comment: i read this post 10min before posting. If there's an encoding issue... which encoding i've to use? I need to keep special chars on it.

Comment: If i knew I would post an answer, not a comment ;) I figured the link might tip some people more knowledgeable in php than I am.

Comment: i need to know how can i generate a mac csv file, not the difference between mac, ms2 and windows csv, and i don't need to know how can i read a mac csv file (i know this already, php can read the end line auto).
It doesn't give me information about how reach the solution of my problem...

Comment: Well, if you know the difference between what you have and what you want, you know what to fix... So knowing what is the difference is very relevant to your problem and does give you insight about how to solve your problem! Again, this is a comment not an answer, you should not expect a comment to give you the solution, merely to bring a little more info to the table.

Comment: So, to spell it out: since the difference between windows and mac csv is encoding and line-ending, it means that Sage is not reading your raw csv properly because of the encoding or line-ending... So you could try to use a different encoding and/or force unix-like line-endings (LF). This may solve your problem. It is a lead, not a solution, I don't know php at all (got here while reviewing your "new user" question)

Comment: ok thanks anyway. I know there is different line-ending and don't mind how line encoding can affect on this but when i post on there is always after, at least a pair of hours searching on internet. So, as others that post on there i need to know how i have to do it, not info that i've readed before to imagine how can i afford this. Cheers!